# Convert Single column C# DataTable to JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

The DataTable contains single column EFFDATE.

```
EFFDATE
2015-06-15
2014-10-21
2014-07-17
2014-07-16
2014-06-17
2014-03-13
```

I have the following code to convert DataTable dttbl to JSON.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dttbl, Formatting.Indented)
```

The output from conversion is

```
[
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2015-06-15"
  },
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2014-10-21"
  },
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2014-07-17"
  },
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2014-07-16"
  },
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2014-06-17"
  },
  {
    "EFFDATE": "2014-03-13"
  }
]
```

The output I want is

```
{
    "EFFDATE": [
        "2015-06-15",
        "2014-10-21",
        "2014-07-17",
        "2014-07-16",
        "2014-06-17",
        "2014-03-13"
    ]
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: no way... JSON needs to explicit the column names in each object

Comment: Does JSON needs to explicit the column or JSON.net needs to do that? The expected JSON is valid. So I think I got to custom-create my own JSON from the DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
              new { EFFDATE = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[0]) }
           );
```

Comment: @stackoverflowuser If you liked it you may want to *accept* it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I was not allowed to. Had to wait for few minutes. Just did.